# DSUM with two conditions from an independent table

Tags: ms-access

I have a form titled "frm-SavedCancellations" built in access 2016 db with a Control Source titled "R-Totals" where I want to write a formula in, same Control Source is based on an independent table called "tbl-Reserves" The table has the following columns: Column-A, Column-B, column-C and Column-Amounts.

I want to populate the "R-Totals" with value(s) from Column-Amounts of the independent table "tbl-Reserves" only if the values in rows in Column_A and Column-B are identical.

I have tried the following:

```
=Nz(DSum("Amounts","tbl-Reserves","Column-A="" And Column-B=" And Amounts\<\>0"))
```

This formula produced a blank control instead of an amount in control "R-Totals"

Your asistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: First NZ needs some value to replace null with, which for a sum is usually 0.  Second if amount = 0 it doesn't affect the sum so no need for that part: NZ(DSum("Amounts", "tbl-Reserves", "(Column-A = Column-B)",0)  This gives you one sum for all the Amounts where Column-A=Column-B for the entire table.  If column A or B can be null you will have to decide how to handle null = something and null = null.

Comment: Column-A=ABCDEFGHSDR  Column-B= 699  Amounts = $20                                                     
Column-A=ABCDEFGHSDR  Column-B= 677  Amounts = $25            
Column-A=ZHGBFGTRGHH  Column-B= 564  Amounts=$100                          
Column-A=ZHGBFGTRGHH  Column-B= 564  Amounts=$120                                                                    
Above is a sample of the values in each cell of "tblReserves". I need to show the sum of the related amounts of the first two identical rows and sum of the next two rows.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
=Nz(DSum("[Amounts]","[tbl-Reserves]","[Column-A] = [Column-B]"))
```

If the columns A or B can be *Null*, apply *Nz* to these, as you can't compare *Null* values:

```
=Nz(DSum("[Amounts]","[tbl-Reserves]","Nz([Column-A]) = Nz([Column-B])"),0)
```

Comment: That seems very much different from your question. So, either rewrite the question or delete this and create a new - in both cases, include the sample data and the expected output.

Comment: see here about what happens when don't include a valueifnull with nz(): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c  in other words if null it returns the empty string or blank.  so you are most likely getting null because something is wrong with the query and that is showing blank

Comment: @mazoula: Yes, that zero was missing. Thanks.